# What open source CRM do you use?

Tags: open-source, crm

What open source(or not) CRM do you use ?
i have come across Tactilecrm and it's kinda' great.

Comment: Good question s.mihai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with [Sugar](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/) some.  It's pretty decent, though last I saw their internal architecture was kind of a mess, and some sort of initiative to use Smarty wherever possible had made it worse. (I was less concerned with using it, more concerned with extending it.)

Answer (score 1):

my workplace currently uses [vtiger](http://www.vtiger.com)

Comment: it's too complex for what we generally use.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using FatFreeCRM, it provides the basic and is then relatively easy to add features using Rails plugins.

Answer (score 0):

drupal is very lightweight and I found it to be rather easy to use and develop for